# Scikit learn make a feature that always guarantees an exact prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a pipeline with sales data and it works great for a lot of products but some are being discontinued and the prediction should return something like 0, I can come up with a feature to say discontinued but I don't know how to make the model always return 0 when this feature shows up.

Currently using scikit pipelines.

Comment: Any reason to not just hard-code such a rule?

Comment: @BenReiniger I wanted to pickle the whole pipeline for production